# How to be aware that when a function is run in angular context?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have an service:

```
angular.module("app").factory("myService", function($rootScope){
    return {
        doSomething: function(){
            console.log('doingSomething', $rootScope.$$phase);
            $rootScope.someVar = true;
        }
    }
});
```

If I run it inside the controller like this

```
angular.module("app").controller("HomeController", function(myService){
    myService.doSomething();
});
```

The console log gives:

```
doingSomething $apply
```

But if I run the service inside a unit test environment

```
it('should doSomething', inject(function(myService) {
    myService.doSomething();
}));
```

The console log only get

```
doingSomething null
```

The typical answer that if you need to trigger the `$digest` cycle yourselves through `$apply()`.  The angular js wiki [mentioned](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29) about `ng-click`, `$timeout` and `$http`, but surely there are other places, such as running inside the controller. How can I determine that without trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are testing.  If you are testing something that requires a digest cycle (like `$broadcast` or `$on` events), then you will need to call `scope.$apply()` or simply `scope.$digest()` in the setup of the test.

However, most of the time, this is not required because services are usually designed as discrete pieces of functionality that do not require the scope.  In the case of an HTTP call, the $httpBackend` service allows you to mock out the response.

For `ng-click`, you shouldn't be using this is a service.  And for a controller you'll be binding to a function that you can test in isolation.

Hope this helps.